# Chain cached variables like selectors in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

Let's say I got two variables like so :
`var a = $('#a'), b = $('#b');`

How can I replace (if this is even possible) `$('#a, #b');` with something using `a` and `b` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
var $foo = a.add(b)
```

[EDIT] Here is a live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veBnR/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I like Jmax's answer, but if you want a bit more options, it seems best to request the id attribute of the element:

```
var myDiv = $("#MYdivID");

...

//then select your div like so:
$("#"+myDiv.attr("id"))
```

it's syntactically a bit more difficult than Jmax's answers, but this way you can work with classes, id's, checked attributes, ... 
Also, this way works better if you tend to build element id's like "#savebutton_1", "#savebutton_2", .... (e.g. in index pages). You get a lot of freedom to build your selector like you want, while still maintaining the option to reference a variable instead of hardcoding a new selector.

For your example:

```
$('#'+ a.attr('id') +', #' + b.attr(id));
```

I admit it's a bit harder to read, but perfectly valid and operational :)

Comment: It works, but I am going with JMax's answer for its concision.

Comment: Point in place, it all depends on what you need :-)